# Change curved lines to straight lines

Tags: d3.js, d3-force-directed

I am trying to make a forced graph, at the moment the link is curved. Does anyone know how to change them to straight lines?

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/fipazayobe/1/edit?html,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #666;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
      }
  </style>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="external-data">
  </div>

  <script>

    // http://blog.thomsonreuters.com/index.php/mobile-patent-suits-graphic-of-the-day/
    var links = [
    {source: "file1", target: "file2", type: "suit", shape: "rect"}
    ];

    var nodes = {};

    // Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
    links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source, shape: link.shape});
    link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target, shape: link.shape});
    });

    var width = 960,
    height = 250;

    var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(150)
    .charge(-300)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

    var svg = d3.select(".external-data").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

    // Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
    svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["suit"])
    .enter().append("marker")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

    var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
    .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });

    var circlesOrRects = svg.append("g").selectAll(".foo")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().size(200)
    .type(function(d) { return d.shape == "rect" ? "circle" : "square"; }))
    .attr("fill", function(d){return d.shape == "rect" ? "blue" : "red"})
    .call(force.drag);

    var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("x", 8)
    .attr("y", ".31em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

    // Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
    function tick() {
    path.attr("d", linkArc);
      circlesOrRects.attr("transform", transform)
    text.attr("transform", transform);
    }

    function linkArc(d) {
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
    dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
    dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
    }

    function transform(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3 force layout: Straight line instead of curve for links (but only for some links)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098879/d3-force-layout-straight-line-instead-of-curve-for-links-but-only-for-some-lin)

Comment: If you check the duplicate post and follow the advice (set `dr = 0` in `linkArc(d)` and test in your jsBin you will get a straight line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could use the answer in the linked duplicate, it's rather silly to create a straight arc if you only want a line.  Just change the `linkArc` function to draw a line:

```
function linkArc(d) {
  return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "L" + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
}
```

Might want to think about renaming the function as it now has nothing to do with arcs...